# Can I display coverage metrics for mutation tests?

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage

In a quality gate, we are able to specify values for 'Mutations Coverage', that specify when a warning or error is generated. Is there a way to display the mutations coverage value.

For example in the **Measures -> Coverage tab?**

This is where It coverage and the number of unit tests are displayed.

Any suggestions would be most welcome

Answer (score 0):

All non-hidden measures (there are some metrics that are hidden either because they're deprecated or because they're calculated solely to feed other metrics) are displayed automatically in the Measures space.

If you have a plugin that's creating Mutations Coverage metrics, those values should already be available. But such measures are not created by default.

Tangential but relevant: SonarQube 6.2 consolidated coverage metrics into simply Coverage. Now you can feed as many coverage reports as you want, assuming the language plugin has been upgraded to support that, but the values are consolidated under the theory that by and large people don't care *how* the code is covered, only *that it is*.